# Finite $2$-groups of order $>32$ and nilpotency class $2$

Tags: finite-groups, 2-groups

I only know $2$-groups of nilpotency class $2$ and order less than or equal to $32$, and wondering if there are finite $2$-groups of order $>32$ and nilpotency class $2$? Your suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are $2$-groups of any order (which is a power of $2$ and at least $8$) and nilpotency class $2$. It is easy enough to construct examples via semidirect products of abelian $2$-groups.

Comment: @ Tobias, can you give an example of such construction please?

Comment: Actually, sorry, that was the wrong way to get examples. Just take direct product of class $2$ ones with abelian ones.

Comment: @ Tobias, many thanks. I now feel cool!

Comment: Search the list of groups of order $64$ [here](http://bruckner.stoch.uni-linz.ac.at/~juergen/GroupTables/TW64.html) for nilpotency class $2$. Therer are already many examples.